# Forces, the last force is missing

Tags: geometry

[image]

So after much calculation 
F1 + F2 + F3 =0
F3 = -F1 - F2
F3 = -[-45i + 31j]-[120i - 44j]
   = 45i-31j-120i+44j
   = -75i + 13j

CORRECT??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object remains at rest if sum of all the forces applied on it is $0$. So, i think whatever you have done is correct (including computations).

Here, $x=-75$